# WordNet in Portuguese

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet

I'm doing a java project where I have to find synonyms of some words. I know WordNet is widely spread, however it is not available in 'portuguese' (the language I'm currently using). Is there something similar to WordNet for the portuguese language?

Thank You.

Comment: @Kev, why is it non-constructive? this seems like a straightforward question that can be answered with a series of links

Comment: @RicardoPietrobon - it's "shopping/recommendation" question, we prefer not to have link only answers. Have a read of the site "Help": http://stackoverflow.com/tour - see the *Don't ask about...* section.

Comment: @Kev, I respectfully disagree. Wordnet is a taxonomy/ontology used for NLP, and so it should fit under "Software development tools" which is in the "do ask" category

Answer (score 2):

I found this on the Wordnet website. I hope it helps.

> Wordnet.PT is a linguistic knowledge
>   database for Portuguese, developed at
>   the Centre of Linguistics of the
>   University of Lisbon
>
> The database, which can be used in
>   several domains in Computational
>   Linguistics and Language Engineering,
>   such as machine translation, search
>   engines, information extraction,
>   applications for teaching Portuguese,
>   among others, is organized according
>   to the general EuroWordNet framework,
>   a multilingual database integrating
>   wordnets for several European
>   languages.
>
> Wordnets are lexical-conceptual
>   networks organized around a set of
>   relations which have been shown by
>   research to correspond to the mental
>   organization of lexical meaning.

http://www.clul.ul.pt/clg/eng/wordnetpt/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I've already seen Wordnet.PT and it's only available online, so it won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can checkout and download OpenWN-PT, the download is in the page http://www.globalwordnet.org/gwa/wordnet_table.html and you can play with it online at
http://casta-net.jp/~kuribayashi/multi/.  Please play with it and help us improve it.
[editing as the code is now in GitHub https://github.com/own-pt and the browsing interface is in http://wnpt.brlcloud.com/wn/]

Comment: Just updating links (they rot, don't they?), download OWN-PT from  github [OWN-PT](https://github.com/own-pt/openWordnet-PT), browse it at [OWN-PT](http://openwordnet-pt.org) and check the [Open Multilingual WordNet](https://omwn.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I found this: http://multiwordnet.fbk.eu/english/home.php

Also: http://www.clul.ul.pt/clg/eng/wordnetpt/index.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I've looked the Multi WordNet, unfortunatly there is this observation: 'Although the Spanish, Portuguese, Hebrew, Romanian and Latin WordNets are compatible with the MultiWordNet model, these wordnets are not part of the MultiWordNet distribution.'